# What is the difference between "revive" and "revive with oxygen"?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

When I go up to a downed teammate, the game gives me two options: "Revive" and "Revive with Oxygen". What is the difference between these two options? How much oxygen does reviving with oxygen consume?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Referring to [this](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/borderlands-the-pre-sequel/Oz_kit) wiki

> The Oz kit is the players oxygen supply (also refered to as O2) which can be used to to perform many different things besides breathing. Your O2 can be used to revive players faster

So you have two choices :

- Using the normal revive
- Using the revive with oxygen, going faster but drawing on your O2 resources